# Prove if $\lim_{x\to \infty }f'(x) = 0$ then $f(x) = \text{Const}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove if $f$ is Differentiable at every point and if $\lim_{x\to   \infty }f'(x) = 0$ then $f(x) = \text{Const}$

Comment: Maybe you would like to say that $f'(x)=0$ then $f$ is constant...

Comment: **Corollary:** if $g$ is a continuous function such that $\lim _{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$, then $g$ is constantly $0$.

Answer (score 8):

This is obviously wrong.

Consider
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

OK, I am sorry, here is a differentiable one,

$$f(x)=e^{-x}$$

Comment: but f is not Differentiable function at x = 0

Comment: Try $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @AmeenAli: As $0$ is quite far from $\infty$, it's extremely simple to fix that, but as the other examples given (in Zack's answer and ajr's comment above) show, that's not even neccessary.

Answer (score 2):

A differentiable example:

$$f(x) = 2^{-x}$$